# How can I get tabulars on facing pages to line up?

Tags: tables, layout

I want to create a two-page spread with a grid across it. So I have this code:

```
\documentclass[letter,openleft,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=0pt,right=0pt,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[OC]{}% Author on Odd page, Centred
  \fancyhead[EC]{Week of \makebox[2in]{\dotfill} to \makebox[2in]{\dotfill}}% Title on Even page, Centred
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Header rule of .4pt
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline &&&&&&\rule{0cm}{5cm}}
\newcounter{theyflines}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt

\newcommand{\apage}{

\adjustbox{clip=true,trim=0pt 0pt {\textwidth} 0pt}{\usebox\tempbox}

\pagebreak\vspace*{\fill}%
\adjustbox{clip=true,trim={\textwidth} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\usebox\tempbox}
}
\newcounter{theyfpages}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\pwidth}
\newlength{\spwidth}

\setlength{\pwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}%
\divide\pwidth by 3
\setlength{\spwidth}{\dimexpr \pwidth-2cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}%

\savebox{\tempbox}{% fit 3 columns into \textwidth
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{\spwidth}|p{\pwidth}|p{\pwidth}|p{\pwidth}|p{\pwidth}|p{\pwidth}|}
\hline
Course & Weekly goal & Monday & Tuesday & Wednesday & Thursday & Friday
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 5}{\aline}\\
\hline
&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{2cm}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\null\newpage

\forloop{theyfpages}{1}{\value{theyfpages} < 41}{\apage}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this result:
[image]

How can I get the rows on the facing pages to line up correctly? I tried playing with the margin options in `geometry`, but that didn't really help.

## Update

I tried wrapping the tabulars in a `textblock` environment with the `textpos` package, but for some reason that stacks all the tabulars on top of each other, as below:
[image]

Comment: You can use the [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package and place the tabulars in a text box with the same coordinates, but on difterent page.